# invariant violation has not been registered on Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, emulation

I created a new Reactive Native project using "npx react-native@latest init TestApp2" in bash on Windows.  When I tried to start up the new app before making modifications to ensure the environment was working correctly, the emulator showed an angry red error that began with "invariant violation: TestApp1 has not been registered on Android emulator".

It then proceeded to list a couple of probable causes including that a version of Metro for another app (TestApp1 in my case) was still running and needed to be killed.  The other one was basically that my app was using the old app name (TestApp1) instead of the new app name (TestApp2).

However, after tracking down the metro process (it was actually the "node" process that used the ":::8081" port specified in the details) and killing it, the issue persisted.

Then I confirmed that all of the places that others suggest might have the old name (TestApp1) had the new name (TestApp2), the issue still persisted.

None of the suggestions I found on-line helped.  It kept failing when it tried to start the emulator.

It did not matter if I killed everything (even rebooted my laptop) and tried again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried those solutions plus others I found on-line to no avail.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me (something similar would probably work for similar issue with the iOS simulator as well).

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.